# Go CRUD with Postgres and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, go

I'm pretty new to go and backend and I'm in a go internship programme. We built a crud that connects to a psql db, and now I've been told to connect mongoDB which we will use for dev, while PSQL will be used for prod.
Do I have to create new handlers from scratch that I will use for mongo or can I use the same handlers and somehow determine the database type which is being used and use the corresponding logic accordingly?
For example, I have this handler for the user registration endpoint:

```
func (ctrl *UserController) Register(c *gin.Context) {
    var user models.User
    if err := c.BindJSON(&user); err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "error":   true,
            "message": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }
    err := ctrl.userService.Register(&user)
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnprocessableEntity, gin.H{
            "error":   true,
            "message": err.Error(),
        })
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, gin.H{
        "message": "successfully created an user",
    })
}

func (svc *UserService) Register(user *models.User) error {
    if svc.userRepo.CheckIfEmailExists(user.Email) {
        return errors.New("user already registered")
    }
    hash, err := svc.generatePasswordHash(user.Password)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New("err can't register user")
    }

    user.Password = hash

    return svc.userRepo.Insert(user)
}

func (repo *UserRepository) CheckIfEmailExists(mail string) bool {
    var user models.User
    err := repo.dbClient.Debug().Model(models.User{}).Where("email = ?", mail).Find(&user).Error
    return errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound)
}

func (repo *UserRepository) Insert(user *models.User) error {
    err := repo.dbClient.Debug().Model(models.User{}).Create(user).Error
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to insert user: %v\n", err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

I built the insert, register and CheckIfEmailExists functions for mongo:

```
func (repo *UserRepository) InsertInMongo(user *models.UserB) error {
    coll := repo.mongoClient.DB.Collection("users")
    _, err := coll.InsertOne(context.TODO(), user)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("failed to insert user: %v\n", err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func (svc *UserService) RegisterToMongo(user *models.UserB) error {
    check := svc.userRepo.CheckIfEmailExistsInMongo(user.Email)
    if check {
        return errors.New("user already registered")
    }
    hash, err := svc.generatePasswordHash(user.Password)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New("err can't register user")
    }
    user.Password = hash
    return svc.userRepo.InsertInMongo(user)
}

func (repo *UserRepository) CheckIfEmailExistsInMongo(email string) bool {
    coll := repo.mongoClient.Collection
    filter := bson.D{{Key: "email", Value: email}}

    count, err := coll.CountDocuments(context.TODO(), filter)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if count != 0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: "_mongoDB which we will use for dev, while PSQL will be used for prod_" - uhh, what? Isn't the whole point of having a dev environment that it should look like the production one so that things can be properly tested? Having two different databases seems to preclude that possibility entirely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide the code of how the UserService is created.

Ideally, you should have an interface like this:

```
type UserRepository interface {
    CheckIfEmailExists(mail string) bool
    Insert(user *models.User) error
    …
}
```

Then, the UserService should be created like this:

```
// We use the interface as param
func NewUserService(userRepo UserRepository) UserService {
    return UserService{
        UserRepo: userRepo
    }
}
```

And you would have two separate repositories, both implementing the `UserRepository` interface - which means they should have the same methods with the same name and same signatures (params, return types) as the interface:

mongo_user_repository.go

```
Type MongoUserRepo struct {
    …
}

func (repo MongoUserRepo) CheckIfEmailExists(mail string) bool {
  … some mongo logic here
}

func (repo MongoUserRepo) Insert(user *models.User) error {
  … some mongo logic here
}
```

postgres_user_repository.go

```
type PostgresUserRepo struct {
    …
}

func (repo PostgresUserRepo) CheckIfEmailExists(mail string) bool {
  … some postgres logic here
}

func (repo PostgresUserRepo) Insert(user *models.User) error {
  … some postgres logic here
}
```

And you can pass either of them, depending on the usecase, as the (very bad) example below:

main.go

```
…

var userService UserService

if os.Getenv(“environment”) == “prod” {
    userService = NewUserService(postgreUserRepo)
} else if os.Getenv(“environment”) == “dev” {
    userService = NewUserService(mongoUserRepo)
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the solution I went for. Thank you!